# PHP array_search not working (returns empty string)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to check if a filename of an image contains "cover". Somehow this stopped working for me (Pretty sure it worked already). I copied the part of my function not working.

```
$name=array("_IMG8555.jpg", "_IMG7769.jpg", "_IMG8458.jpg", "Cover.jpg", "_IMG7184.jpg");
$cov=array("Cover.png","Cover.jpg","Cover.jpeg", "cover.png","cover.jpg","cover.jpeg");
```

This does not work for me:

```
print_r(array_search($cov, $name)); //Returns empty String
print_r($name[array_search($cov, $name)]); //Returns first element of the name Array
```

Also I added a test Strings to make sure this is not result the searched string is the same as the search value.

```
print_r($name[3]===$cov[1]); //Returns true(1)
```

Can anyone help? Why does this simple script not work?

I also tried using `in_array()` but this is not working either.

Comment: where do you provide your file_name to search! i find it no where.

Comment: First parameter of the `array_search` should a string (filename) you want to search in second array.

Comment: You need to flip the `needle` and the `haystack`, plus you're passing both the arguments as array. RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Comment: The filenames are in the $name array, the $cov array contains the search String with different file endings. Isn't it possible to search for all $cov elements in $name, so it will return the index of the first result in $name? (index 3)

Comment: You are searching an array inside another array, which of course does not get found, so `array_search()` returns FALSE. So in the first line: `print_r(array_search($cov, $name));` you don't see anything, because you got FALSE. In the second line FALSE gets converted to 0 and you get the first element. But I still don't see what exactly you are trying to do here. **What is the expected output?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array_search() function search an array for a value and returns the key

```
array_search(key_value,array)
```

Loop your $cov array and get one key at a time and check with $name array

```
foreach($cov as $i => $cov_s){
 if(in_array($cov_s, $name)){
  return $name[array_search($cov_s, $name)];
 }
}
return $name[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$name=array("_IMG8555.jpg", "_IMG7769.jpg", "_IMG8458.jpg", "Cover.jpg", "_IMG7184.jpg"); 
$cov=array("Cover.png","Cover.jpg","Cover.jpeg", "cover.png","cover.jpg","cover.jpeg");

foreach($cov as $c){
    if(array_search($c,$name)){
         //Do your success function
         return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```